# Something is wrong with scroll bar and content

Tags: html, css

Something is wrong with my code.

1. I don't understand why the scrollbar is visible?
2. Why do I need to add `<br />` to content for the text will be show?

[image: Screenshot]

```css
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
#header {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #ededed;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 70px;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
#footer {
  background: #ffab62;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="" class="closebtn" onclick="clear()">&times;</a>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="myUL">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>סה"כ: 50 ש"ח</p>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="site">
    <div id="header">

      <ul>
        <div id="referNav">
          <li>
            <div id="referLink1"><a href="#" class="active">הזמנה חדשה</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div id="referLink2"><a href="#" class="">2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #header -->

  <div id="content">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
    <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- #wrapper -->
```

Comment: please explain your question properly and what does the picture represent? your problem or the solution that you want?

Comment: the picture represent my problem. you can see in the picture that scrool bar is visible and the content div show the text only if i add <br> tag.

Comment: i dont see any scrollbar here.What do you meant by " visible div show the text only if i add <br> tag"?
your text are perfectly visible.

Comment: your given image and snippet doesnot match

Comment: ohh... sorry you right.. anyway, you can see in the snippet that in the content div i added <br> tag because if I didnt do that the header will hide this.

Comment: you can see in the picture that the scrool bar is visible ..

Comment: can you please share your code in proper order so that the problem is identifiable!

Comment: i have tried removing the <br>! its completely alright!
what do you meant by "the header will hide this " ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `<body>` and the scrollbar should be hidden. I don't know the answer to your second question, but I think I've gave you the answer for the first question.

Comment: I want to hidden scrollbar only if didn't need him. no absolute to hide him.